# How to have a bootstrap "header row" that stacks with correct items underneath each header on mobile

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the items to stay under the correct heading when it stacks on mobile, instead of the two header rows stacking right on top of each other then all the items under both of them if that makes sense? I've tried several combinations of rows/nesting and tables instead of rows, but can't seem to find the right combination to have it look like it does now on desktop then stack with the correct items under the correct header on mobile. Is this possible or am I trying to do something beyond the scope of what bootstrap simplicity is meant for?

```
<div class="container">      
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
  Gold Level
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
  Silver Level
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  Gold benefit 1
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  Silver benefit 1
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  Gold benefit 2
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  Silver benefit 2
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  Gold benefit 3
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  Silver benefit 3
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could do this. These easiest is to keep all the `col-` in a single `.row` and use the ordering classes...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 order-first" style="background-color:yellow;">
            Gold Level
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
            Silver Level
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 order-first order-sm-0">
            Gold benefit 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            Silver benefit 1
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 order-first order-sm-0">
            Gold benefit 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            Silver benefit 2
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 order-first order-sm-0">
            Gold benefit 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            Silver benefit 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/xfoOBsoVF0